# Insert a config value into Blade view in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to insert a Laravel config value into a view (more precisely, into a JavaScript variable inside a Vue template).

I' trying:

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = "<?php echo config('app.boshurl') ?>";
```

And

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = "{{ config('app.boshurl') }}";
```

But none of these works.

Comment: first run ```php artisan config:cache``` and check agani

Comment: Thanks @MohammadB, but thats not the problem since I see this `var BOSH_SERVICE = "{{ config('app.boshurl') }}";` in the HTML source code.

Comment: do you have "*.blade.php" on the file name?

Comment: @RavishaHesh its a `.vue` file

Comment: then you can't use php tags or blade syntax inside it

Comment: Sorry, big mistake from myself.

Answer (score 3):

I was executing that code from a VUE file. Of course it will never work